# Covariance estimation in a big data setting

Tags: covariance, bias, large-data

I don't seem to understand how to estimate the unbiased covariance of a big dataset, $X_{n,p}$. Suppose this dataset is to large to fit in memory: I have a billion samples in a moderate number of dimensions, say p=8.

My intuition says that the following naive strategy might be used to solve the problem:

1) Partition the dataset sample-wise in smaller chunks $X_{n,p}$  $\rightarrow$ $X1_{m, p}, X2_{m, p}, ..., Xk_{m, p}$

2) For each partition, calculate the corresponding covariance estimation $\hat{\Sigma}_1,  \hat{\Sigma}_2, \hat{\Sigma}_{...}, \hat{\Sigma}_k$ sequentially.

3) Finally, pool the intermediate covariance results using the correct formula's to obtain the final solution, $\Sigma_{Pooled}$

This strategy obviously won't work: in the same way that the naive covariance is influenced by possible outliers in the dataset, it is highly sensitive to the partition sample size (and possibly the $m/p$ ratio, I don't know) - resulting in a severe biased estimation.

My question is thus as follows: how could I tackle this practical problem? Could anyone pinpoint me to relevant literature?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either an incremental (add one data point at a time) or pairwise algorithm (which can be applied repeatedly).

For variance, updating formulas are well-known and discussed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Parallel_algorithm as well as in more depth at "UPDATING FORMULAE AND A PAIRWISE ALGORITHM FOR COMPUTING SAMPLE VARIANCES" Chan, Golub, and LeVeque 1979 http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/79/773/CS-TR-79-773.pdf .

The extension to covariance is presented in "Formulas for Robust, One-Pass Parallel Computation of Covariances and Arbitrary-Order Statistical Moments" Pebay 2008 http://prod.sandia.gov/techlib/access-control.cgi/2008/086212.pdf